# An adjective or a noun to describe a very small apartment / house etc

Tags: word-request

I was wondering if there is a pejorative or sarcastic adjective to attribute to a so small house in which you barely can swing a cat [the popular English expression].

In my language we call such apartments / houses / offices and totally places (as they mostly are like that today, :)] a matchbox-sized appartment or house, but I would appreciate it if you help me find the closest terms in English for describing these types of places.

Thank you.

Comment: Idioms like this tend to depend on the region or dialect. Where are you planning on using the word?

Answer (score 7):

For an apartment, the term *broom closet* is often used.  The notion being that the living space is small enough to be only used as a storage closet.  This is more sarcastic and not necessarily horribly pejorative.  Using it in reference to an apartment's size is actually the example they use for "teensy" in this [thesaurus](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/teensy) entry.

For a house, [*hovel*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hovel) or [*shanty*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shanty) can be a derogatory term (normally associated with a small hut or cabin but more of a commentary on the *quality* of the property, rather than the size), but both are generally very insulting.

Answer (score 7):

"Matchbox sized" is used occasionally, and the meaning is clear. "Shoebox sized" is an alternative.  You could also talk about "micro-apartment", or any of the ususal words meaning "small": tiny, little, pint-sized.  Estate agents use words like "compact" or "bijou" which also mean "small".

Slightly more formally A "studio apartment" is a one-room apartment which combines living, sleeping and cooking spaces into a single room. Another term for the same thing is a "bed-sit", though this is slightly dated.

Comment: Note that technically "studio apartment" is about the layout rather than the size (but in practise most of them are small).

Answer (score 3):

I've heard small houses politely called "quaint" or "cozy". This is a tongue-in-cheek usage of these terms. A realtor might use "cozy" as a positive thing, but someone looking at the dwelling might be using the word sarcastically to mean, "too small."

Comment: "Cozy" was the first one that came to mind for me too. I always picture someone walking into such an apartment for the first time and awkwardly saying "Well this is...cozy."

Answer (score 0):

I can also add such words as *cabin, shack, hut, lodge*. They are mostly suitable for houses, but I think some of them can be successfully used for flats too.

Comment: All of those are normally used to describe *detached* dwellings, so it would be confusing to use them for something like a flat/apartment.